# The definition of the vacuum state of quantum field by path-integral

Tags: wavefunction, hilbert-space, path-integral, boundary-conditions, wick-rotation

In the review *Entanglement entropy of black holes* by Sergey Solodukhin ([arXiv:1104.3712](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3712), equation 13), I see a definition of vacuum state of quantum field by path integral over half of the total Euclidean spacetime defined as $\tau\leq 0$ such that the quantum field satisfies the fixed boundary condition $\psi(\tau=0,x,z)=\psi_{0}(x,z)$ on the boundary of the half-space:
$$\Psi[\psi_{0}(x,z)]=\int_{\psi(X)|_{\tau=0}=\psi_{0}(x,z)}D\psi e^{-W[\psi]}\tag{13},$$ where $W$ is the action.

I can't understand what does this mean. I learned that in canonical quantization, a vacuum state is defined by Hamiltonian of the quantum field, which has the lowest energy. But here in path integral. I want to know the meaning of the above definition of vacuum state, why should we define it in this way?

Comment: Starting from any state $|\psi\rangle$ which has non-zero overlap with the vacuum, imaginary time evolution projects it to the ground state (i.e. the vacuum): $|\psi_g\rangle=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}e^{-HT}|\psi\rangle$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian. One can rewrite the imaginary time evolution as a Euclidean path integral and the $|\psi\rangle$ becomes the initial condition (or the boundary condition, in a relativistic theory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) Let us here phrase the problem in the context of some position operator $\hat{q}$ of QM for simplicity. The generalization to QFT can formally be achieved by replacing the position operator $\hat{q}$ with a quantum field $\hat{\psi}({\bf x})$.

We know that the overlap with Minkowski (M) signature is given as a [path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation)

$$\begin{align}
K(q_f,&t_f;q_i,t_i)\cr
~\equiv~&\langle q_f,t_f\mid q_i,t_i\rangle\cr
~=~&\langle q_f,t_i\mid \exp\left[ -\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H} \Delta t \right] \mid q_i,t_i\rangle\cr
~=~&\sum_{n}\langle q_f,t_i\mid n \rangle \exp\left[ -\frac{i}{\hbar}E_n \Delta t \right]\langle n\mid q_i,t_i\rangle\cr
~=~&\int_{q(t_i)=q_i}^{q(t_f)=q_f} \! {\cal D}q~\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}S_M[q]\right], \end{align} \tag{O} $$
where $\Delta t:=t_f-t_i$ and $\mid n \rangle$ is an energy basis for the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$.

II) For fixed initial values $(q_i,t_i)$, we may identify the overlap (O) with the the wave function(al) $\Psi(q_f,t_f)$. Alternatively, for fixed final values $(q_f,t_f)$, we may identify the overlap (O) with the complex conjugate of the wave function(al) $\Psi^{\ast}(q_i,t_i)$. Solodukhin is doing the latter.

III) Next [Wick rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) to Euclidean variables $S_M=iS_E$, $\tau=it$, $\tau_i=it_i$, $\tau_f=it_f$, etc. Notice that the ground state (=vacuum) contribution $E_0$ in the overlap (1) becomes completely dominant in the large time limit $ \tau_f \to \infty$, cf. comment by Meng Cheng. In that limit, the wave function(al) $\Psi^{\ast}(q_i,t_i)$ becomes the vacuum wave function(al).

The translation to Solodukhin's formula (13) is straightforward.

Comment: Something I never quite understood about this derivation is that it seems to only work when the spectrum of excitations of the theory has a finite energy gap relative to the vacuum. If the spectrum is continuous and you have excited states with arbitrarily low energies (which is the case in any theory with massless particles in flat space, for example), then it is not obvious that you can claim that the overlap with the vacuum will be the only completely dominant contribution. Do we need to assume some sort of IR regularization in order to make sense of this?

Comment: Hi @Bruno De Souza Leão. Thanks for the feedback. Good point.